# Variables in column name in PHP and MySQLi statements

Tags: php, variables, mysqli

I have the following statement:

```
mysqli_prepare($link, "UPDATE tresults SET q31_red = ?, q31_theme = ? WHERE result_id = ?;");
```

The above is fine **but** I need the `31` element to be a variable, have tried the below but not joy:

```
mysqli_prepare($link, "UPDATE tresults SET q".$qn."_red = ?, q".$qn."_theme = ? WHERE result_id = ?;");
```

No joy - I'm sure this should be possible, any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you should build the query before you prepare it.

Comment: Maybe the issue is with how $qn is getting set. Have you tried storing the query string as a separate variable and then using that variable in the prepare function? That way you can debug the string prior to execution. If you post more of the surrounding code, that may help.

Comment: What you're doing should work. But the fact that you need to do this suggests poor schema design. You shouldn't have numbered columns like that, you should have another table with columns like `result_id_fk`, `question_number`, `question_red`, `question_theme`.

Comment: .'$qn'.  or .trim($qn). can make a trick

Comment: What does `echo mysqli_error($link)` show when you try the problem query?

Comment: Try this: `mysqli_prepare($link, "UPDATE tresults SET ? = ?, ? = ? WHERE result_id = ?;");` and after that populate the values with your variables

Comment: @ad_on_is You can't use placeholders for column names, you should know that.